# want to create api with nodejs loopback

Tags: node.js, loopback

I'm new nodejs with loopback. I want to create an API like leaves/leave_type. I created model leaves but want to create leaves/leave_type

[image]

Comment: this link will help you: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-methods.html

Comment: yes. it working. thank you

Comment: I tried the remote method, I create API, but when I try to post I got an error with status code 401

{ "error": { "statusCode": 401, "name": "Error", "message": "Authorization Required", "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED"

} }

Comment: What is the baseModel of your defined model?

Comment: "base": "PersistedModel "

Comment: So the problem is somewhere else. Could you provide your code? (You can publish it as another question)

Comment: Login using the credentials and paste the Token in the right corner of the Explorer(Token input)

Comment: hey, I find the error. I created ACL in leave.json. so when I post it shows authorized error